# Qt 5.5 QOpenGLWidget link error not linking any openGL calls

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, desktop

I tried to build a simple OpenGL App with Qt 5.5.1, and everything is fine up until I try to use openGL native function calls like glClearColor.

The Widget actually compiles and produces a black screen, but after I try to use any openGL native function it doesn't even link, but produces the error:

`glwidget.cpp:10: error: undefined reference to '_imp__glClearColor@16'`

Here is the .pro file:

```
            QT       += core gui opengl

            CONFIG   += windows

            greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

            TARGET = Vehicle_simulation

            TEMPLATE = app

            SOURCES += main.cpp\
                    simulation.cpp \
                glwidget.cpp

            HEADERS  += simulation.h \
                glwidget.h

            FORMS    += simulation.ui
```

I'm using Desktop Qt mingw492_32 kit.
The strange thing though is that I did not find libQtOpenGL.so in the lib folder. Is my QT installation faulty? I tried to reinstall it multiple times, but it didn't help. Where can I download that specific library?

linking it to the project would solve the problem, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

The problem is the openGL module is missing from the QT installation, **it's not** that I am unable to link to it.

Comment: @genpfault , not to be picky, but the duplicate suggestion is wrong. I found the source of the problem and it's because QT by default builds with ANGLE, which only supports openGL ES, not desktop openGL. To solve this I have to do a custom build of QT Core with openGL in it. I'd be more, than glad to answer the question if someone wouléd encounter this problem.

Comment: After opening an example openGL project which compiled and linked, I found the source of the problem, it is not a linking error, I used the wrong implementation of GLWIdget, I will post my answer as soon as I can compile enough thought to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After I opened up an example program by chance, just to take a look at the implementation; I found that the same `QOpenGLWidget` has been implemented in a new example program.

After a bit of analysis I managed to figure out the problem.

QT has an internal openGL implementation and native openGL support as well. The widget I used inherited from `QOpenGLWidget`, but the openGL function calls (like `glClearColor`) tried to access native openGL implementation in Qt. which Since those were not included in my Qt build, the project would not build.

To fix this one has to either run a custom Qt core build, or use the openGL wrapper provided by Qt.

I used the Qt wrapper in the end, which was also used by the example program [Cube](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-cube-example.html). the class used to implement the widget (called `GLWidget` in my implementation) has to inherit not only from `QOpenGLWidget`, but also from `QOpenGLFunctions`. The latter part was missing from my implementation. The source code for it is the following:

**glwidget.h (initial):**

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H


#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>

class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent);

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
};

#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

**glwidget.h (fixed):**

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H


#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>

class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent);

protected:
    void initializeGL() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    void paintGL() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    void resizeGL(int w, int h) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

## Be careful!

Before any gl* functions are used the function `initializeOpenGLFunctions();` has to be called, otherwise a very cryptic run-time error will pop up.
i.e.:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL(){
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
}
```

Hope this will help someone else as well.

Comment: thanks. it helped. please consider adding reference source as well.

Comment: Glad to be of help! One reference would be the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688370/qt-5-5-with-qmake-linker-cannot-resolve-opengl-function-calls - From there I was curious to see the classes it used, looked into the source, and tried various attempts until it worked.

Comment: versions of qt prior to 5 were including export library for opengl into build, qt5 does own wrapper that is built by principle  rightness over performance, so you call class methods or wrappers  rather library functions. there is virtue in both approaches